# Why am I getting 'Permission Denied' on my static assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question basically says it all. When I try to access my calendar page (which contains events), I get the following error:

```
Permission denied - /Users/usernam/sitter/tmp/cache/assets/development/sass
  (in /Users/username/sitter/app/assets/stylesheets/events.css.scss)
```

i've done a chmod 777 on all directories in my rails directory (i.e in myapp directory, i've done chmod 777 *).

Not sure what I should be doing instead or in addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a -R to your chmod. Simply adding the star will only do the files. Chmod -R 777 * should work. Although you may have some ownership issues that need to be addressed. I would look into using chown instead of granting all access to everyone.